# Iterate over a URL and add/replace string if needed

Tags: javascript, url, shopify, currency

I have an eCommerce Shopify URL that I need to check for a particular string to determine to change the currency or not.
When the user lands on the site, the URL is e.g. https://www.myshop.com.

In the navigation bar, there are buttons that allow the user to change from the default USD currency to their local currency.
This is a native Shopify feature that requires you to add ***?currency=GBP*** (for example to British Pounds) to the URL.

I check if the string ***?currency=*** exists, and if it does it means the user has selected a currency already, but want to change it again. So I strip out 13 characters from the start of the ***?*** and then replace it with the new currency string.

The problem is if someone lands on the site from an ad, the URL might look like https://www.myshop.com?HkuhJKh6876MJ.

Then I have to change the currency URL to ***&*** instead of ***?***
I can iterate over the string and check for more than 1 ***?*** and then change the URL, but it seems long-winded. Is there a better way to do this?

Below is my current code to check for the ***?currency=*** substring and remove and replace it if it exists with a new currency.

```
<input type="button" value="Show USD" onclick="showUSD()">
<input type="button" value="Show GBP" onclick="showAUD()">

<script>
    function showUSD() {
        var changeToCurrency = "USD"; // Set selected currency
        checkForSubstring(changeToCurrency); // Check for '?currency=' substring
    }

    function showGBP() {
        var changeToCurrency = "GBP";
        checkForSubstring(changeToCurrency);
    }

    // Check for substring
    function checkForSubstring (newCurrency) {
        var urlString = window.location.href + "";
        var currencySubstring = "?currency="; 

        if ((urlString.includes(currencySubstring))) {
            sliceURL(urlString, currencySubstring, newCurrency);
        }
        else {
            alert("Doesnt contain substring. \nLoading new URL.");
            window.location.replace(urlString + currencySubstring + newCurrency);
        }
    }

    // Slice URL
    function sliceURL (originalURL, stringToSlice, currency) {
        var n = originalURL.indexOf(stringToSlice); // Get position of substring
        // Slice substring from URL
        var S = originalURL + "";
        var bindex = n; 
        var eindex = n + 13;
        S = S.substr(0, bindex) + S.substr(eindex);
        // Reload new URL
        reloadURL(S, stringToSlice, currency);
    }

    // Reload URL
    function reloadURL(baseURL, stc, currency) {
        window.location.replace(baseURL + stc + currency);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Not sure I got the question right. Can you not just search for "currency=" instead?

Comment: Use library to parse queryString like https://www.npmjs.com/package/query-string

Comment: Check [URLSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams)

Comment: this can be accomplished better with cookies.

Answer (score 1):

The method below will replace the currency value in the query string if there is  **currency**  present in **window.location.search**

```
 let updateCurrency = (CUR)=>{

    let queryString = window.location.search;
    if(queryString && queryString.length){
        queryString = queryString.slice(1);
        queryStringData = queryString.split("&");
        queryStringData.forEach((query,index)=>{
               query = query.split("=")
               if(query[0]== 'currency'){
                queryStringData.splice(index,1);
                queryStringData = queryStringData.join('&')
                            window.location.search =queryStringData +'&currency='+CUR
            }

        });

    }

    }
```